# 日本語に違和感: 「マイナス投票する」の...に代わるものは？の説明

Tags: バグ, 延期, 翻訳, 日本語, ヘルプ

ページの下の方にある以下の部分の最初の文「プラス投票の権限に...」はここでの説明としては変です。
「代わるものは?」に対する説明なのに、プラス投票の「権限」について言及する内容になっています。

実は英文の方も変に見えます。

おそらく「プラス投票の権限」ページへのリンクを貼る関係で語句・文章に制約が入ったと思われます。

日本語版 [マイナス投票する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

> **マイナス投票に代わるものは?**
> プラス投票の権限に集中すべきなので (優れた内容をトップに押し上げます)、そちらが先です。マイナス票は極端な場合のためにとっておいてください。コミュニケーションや編集の代わりを意図するものではありません。

英語版 [vote down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

> **What are the alternatives to downvoting?**
> The upvote privilege comes first because that's what you should focus on: pushing great content to the top.
> Downvoting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing.

---

本来記述したい(すべき)内容はこちらでは無いかと思われます。
候補として：

意訳風

- マイナス投票は行わず、優れた内容の方をプラス投票でトップに押し上げることに集中すべきです。

直訳風の倒置

- 優れた内容をトップの方に押し上げる：プラス投票の権限が最初に来るのは、それはあなたが焦点を当てるべきものだからです。

直訳風

- プラス投票の権限が最初に来るのは、それはあなたが焦点を当てるべきものだからです：優れた内容をトップの方に押し上げる。

---

そして「マイナス票は極端な...」はそれに続けるのではなく、改行で新しい行の先頭から始める方が良いでしょう。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kunif さんがこちらのご提案を投稿くださりました後に英語版 [vote-down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) ページが編集され、2021年6月現在の英語版では以下のテキストが表示されております。

[image: What are the alternatives to downvoting?]

つきましては日本語版では、特に反対意見も見られませんでしたので @kunif さんの直訳風の倒置と、現在の英語版にあわせた以下の形で、変更を依頼させていただく予定です。反映までどうぞしばらくお待ちくださいませ。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: こちらの投稿にマイナス票が投じられたということは、どなたかが「反映すべきではない」と意思表示をなさっているのではないかと、早速ですがヘルプの翻訳[改善ページを投稿いたしました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3615/14055)。