# ヘルプページ「マイナス投票する」を改善したい

Tags: 討議, 翻訳, ヘルプ

「[マイナス投票する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)」のヘルプページを改善したいのですが、みなさんのお声をぜひお伺いしたいです。実はこの言い回しを変えたい、などご意見をお持ちの方がおられるのではないかと思いました。編集合戦のようなものはもちろん避けたいのですが、改善したい（或いは昔の言い回しのほうが良いと思う理由）など、建設的なものであればどのようなご意見でもかまいませんので、みなさんのお声をヘルプページに反映できればと思います。もしよろしければ、回答欄に下書きをコミュニティwikiとして投稿いたしますので、どうぞお使いくださいませ。

英語版ヘルプの第二パラグラフ「[When should I vote down?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)」の箇所は、どうやら今年に入って変更されていたようです。尚、 HTML から Markdown に変えたいという方も、どうぞご編集くださいませ。

Comment: 先の記事の回答に付いたコメント無しのマイナス投票そのものが、私が改善したいと考えた状況と同類のものですね。今回の変更は一歩前進と考えているので私はマイナス投票していませんが、もっと改善したいというのは、既にこちらの記事に書いています。[ヘルプセンター: 「マイナス投票する」の…に代わるものは？の候補追加](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3412/26370)

Answer (score 2):

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down の改善案です。
英語版はこちら: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

---

#### マイナス投票とは?

マイナス投票とは、「マイナス票の投票」とも呼ばれ、どの質問および回答が最も役に立たないかをコミュニティが示す方法です。

#### どんな時にマイナス投票したらいいですか?

はなはだしくずさんな、まったく努力していない投稿、または明らかに、そして危険なほど不正確な回答を見つけたら、マイナス票を使用してください。

1 日に投票できる数には制限があり、その上回答へのマイナス票は*信用度を若干消費*するので、よく考えて使ってください。

#### マイナス投票の方法は?

各投稿の左の大きな下向き矢印をクリックします。

同じボタンをクリックすると投票を取り消すことができますが、短い時間の間だけなので、クリックは慎重に行ってください。マイナス票をプラス票に変更するには上向き矢印をクリックします。逆の場合も同じです。

#### マイナス投票するとどうなりますか?

マイナス投票すると、その内容が「下」に移動して多くの人に見られにくくなります。回答へのマイナス投票は、軽々しく行ってほしくないため、無料ではありません。

- マイナス投票すると、投稿の所有者から信用度が **2** 点削除されます。
- *回答*にマイナス投票すると、投票者自身から信用度が **1** 点削除されます。
- *質問*へのマイナス票は**無料**です。([その理由は?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/))
- UTC の 1 日あたり **30** 回投票できます。質問のみ、追加で **10** 票あります。([その理由は?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/))

#### マイナス投票に代わるものは?

優れた内容をトップの方に押し上げる：[プラス投票の権限](/help/privileges/vote-up)が最初に来るのは、それはあなたが焦点を当てるべきものだからです。マイナス票はコミュニケーションや編集の代わりを意図するものではありません。

マイナス投票の代わりに：

- 投稿がスパムや不快である場合は、[**通報**します](/help/privileges/flag-posts)。
- 質問が重複またはトピックから外れている場合は、[**通報**してモデレーターの注意を喚起します](/help/privileges/flag-posts)。
- 何かが間違っている場合は[**コメント**](/help/privileges/comment)を残すか[投稿を**編集**](/privileges/edit)して訂正してください。